# launch.json configuration for debugging client side javascript without using a web server

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

The `launch.json`'s **Chrome** configuration by default assumes that I am using a Web server. Its content are as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

What if I want to debug a client side JavaScript but I am not using a Web server. My pages are simple HTML pages. Can I still use VS Code extension "Debugger for Chrome" to do this? Or something else may be?

Is it possible to use the `file:///` protocol inside the `url` property of the `launch.json` to enable client side JavaScript debugging in Visual Studio without using a Web server.

I can't find any documentation that addresses this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below Json in `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/mypage.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/wwwroot"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
        },
    ]
}
```

You can find more explanation in the below mentioned URL 
 [VSCODE JS DEBUG](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)

Comment: Thank you very much. So, I have to change the launch.json for every html file I need to run and debug?

Comment: $(file)  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference for the current file.